# No rule to make target error after upgrading Gradle version

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android NDK project that's building normally using the Gradle plugin 3.4.1, and Gradle 5.1.1. I'm trying to upgrade both (ideally the latest versions), but I'm getting this error when I try newer versions:

```
> Task :app:externalNativeBuildGameDebug FAILED
Build game_armeabi-v7a
make: *** No rule to make target `game'.  Stop.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildGameDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /Users/mariano/Documents/android/ndk_r19c/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/mariano/Documents/repo/Game/proj.android/app/src/main/cpp/Android.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=/Users/mariano/Documents/repo/Game/proj.android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/gameDebug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/mariano/Documents/repo/Game/proj.android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/gameDebug/lib APP_CFLAGS+=-DUSE_FILE32API APP_CFLAGS+=-DASSET_PNG=1 APP_CFLAGS+=-DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 APP_CFLAGS+=-DDEBUG=1 APP_CPPFLAGS+=-frtti APP_CPPFLAGS+=-fexceptions APP_CPPFLAGS+=-ffunction-sections APP_CPPFLAGS+=-fdata-sections APP_CPPFLAGS+=-fvisibility=hidden APP_CPPFLAGS+=-DUSE_FILE32API APP_CPPFLAGS+=-DASSET_PNG=1 APP_CPPFLAGS+=-DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 APP_CPPFLAGS+=-DDEBUG=1 -j4 APP_STL=c++_static COMMIT_COUNT=17039 PREFIX_PATH=/Users/mariano/Documents/repo/Game/proj.android/app/src/game/cpp NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_OPTIM=debug PREFIX_NAME=Prefix.pch game}

  make: *** No rule to make target `game'.  Stop.
```

I tried updating both versions one by one, and I start getting this problem when I get to plugin version 3.5.0 and Gradle 5.4.1.

I've seen similar questions but they don't seem to apply to my problem. Can anyone point me to where the problem may be?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this, but I'm not sure why it worked... I'm writing this in case it helps someone with a similar issue.

In my android.mk file, I had `LOCAL_MODULE := game_android`. Changing that to `LOCAL_MODULE := game` fixed the issue and I could upgrade to the latest Gradle version and build the project successfully.

Now, why it worked with older Gradle versions and why the newer versions didn't work with the old name... no idea.